# jQuery ready function not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So basically, I have 2 pictures, and below I have a selection of choices, 5 choices that each hold the value 1-5. I want the picture to change depending on my option choice.

test2.php

```
<?php
                        echo "<form action='./test2.php' method='post'>
                            <select id='tier' name='tier' style='width:100%;'>
                                <option value='1'>Bronze</option>
                                <option value='2'>Silver</option>
                                <option value='3'>Gold</option>
                                <option value='4'>Platinum</option>
                                <option value='5'>Diamond</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name='division' style='width:100%;'>
                                <option value='1'>I</option>
                                <option value='2'>II</option>
                                <option value='3'>III</option>
                                <option value='4'>IV</option>
                                <option value='5'>V</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name='lp' style='width:100%;'>
                                <option value='1'>0-20</option>
                                <option value='2'>21-40</option>
                                <option value='3'>41-60</option>
                                <option value='4'>61-80</option>
                                <option value='5'>81-100</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='1' />
                            <input type='submit' name='add_to_cart' value='Add to cart' style='width:206%;'/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>";

              echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="width:50%;">
                <div>
                  <div class="item-icon">
                    <img name="postTier" id="postTier" src="images/bronze_rank.png" style="width:100%"></img>
                    <p style="line-height: 60px;">Your finished division</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item-details">';
                            echo "<select name='post_tier' style='width:100%;'>
                                <option value='1'>Bronze</option>
                                <option value='2'>Silver</option>
                                <option value='3'>Gold</option>
                                <option value='4'>Platinum</option>
                                <option value='5'>Diamond</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name='post_division' style='width:100%;'>
                                <option value='1'>I</option>
                                <option value='2'>II</option>
                                <option value='3'>III</option>
                                <option value='4'>IV</option>
                                <option value='5'>V</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>";
                        ?>
```

Don't worry about the divs and so on inbetween the code, I have a lot of more html code above the php tag.

Before the end of my html, this is how my javascript code looks like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#tier").change(function(){
    switch($(this).val()) {
        case 0:
           newsrc = 'images/bronze_rank.png';
            break;
        case 1:
            newsrc = 'images/silver_rank.png';
            break;
        case 2:
           newsrc = 'images/gold_rank.png';
            break;
        case 3:
            newsrc = 'images/platinum_rank.png';
            break;
        case 4:
           newsrc = 'images/diamond_rank.png';
            break;
    }
     $("#preTier").attr("src",newsrc);

    });

    });
    </script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#post_tier").change(function(){
    switch($(this).val()) {
        case 0:
           newsrc = 'images/bronze_rank.png';
            break;
        case 1:
            newsrc = 'images/silver_rank.png';
            break;
        case 2:
           newsrc = 'images/gold_rank.png';
            break;
        case 3:
            newsrc = 'images/platinum_rank.png';
            break;
        case 4:
           newsrc = 'images/diamond_rank.png';
            break;
    }
     $("#postTier").attr("src",newsrc);

    });

    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The image never changes on either of the two pictures.
EDIT: I'd like to add that the $(document).ready function never gets called because I've logged it. I don't understand why it doesn't get called when I change the options over and over again.

EDIT: Picture after getting some help [Nothing happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDL1n.png)

Some Extra stuff down here:

```
 <!-- Include jQuery Js -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="assets/js/wow.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
  <!-- Gmap3.js For Static Maps -->
  <script src="assets/js/gmap3.js"></script>
  <!-- Include Waypoint Js -->
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include Ajax MailChimp Js -->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include Custom Js </-->
  <script src="assets/js/custom.min.js"></script>
```

wow.min.js

```
  (function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f=function(a,b){return function(){return a.apply(b,arguments)}},g=[].indexOf||function(a){for(var b=0,c=this.length;c>b;b++)if(b in this&&this[b]===a)return b;return-1};b=function(){function a(){}return a.prototype.extend=function(a,b){var c,d;for(c in b)d=b[c],null==a[c]&&(a[c]=d);return a},a.prototype.isMobile=function(a){return/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(a)},a.prototype.createEvent=function(a,b,c,d){var e;return null==b&&(b=!1),null==c&&(c=!1),null==d&&(d=null),null!=document.createEvent?(e=document.createEvent("CustomEvent"),e.initCustomEvent(a,b,c,d)):null!=document.createEventObject?(e=document.createEventObject(),e.eventType=a):e.eventName=a,e},a.prototype.emitEvent=function(a,b){return null!=a.dispatchEvent?a.dispatchEvent(b):b in(null!=a)?a[b]():"on"+b in(null!=a)?a["on"+b]():void 0},a.prototype.addEvent=function(a,b,c){return null!=a.addEventListener?a.addEventListener(b,c,!1):null!=a.attachEvent?a.attachEvent("on"+b,c):a[b]=c},a.prototype.removeEvent=function(a,b,c){return null!=a.removeEventListener?a.removeEventListener(b,c,!1):null!=a.detachEvent?a.detachEvent("on"+b,c):delete a[b]},a.prototype.innerHeight=function(){return"innerHeight"in window?window.innerHeight:document.documentElement.clientHeight},a}(),c=this.WeakMap||this.MozWeakMap||(c=function(){function a(){this.keys=[],this.values=[]}return a.prototype.get=function(a){var b,c,d,e,f;for(f=this.keys,b=d=0,e=f.length;e>d;b=++d)if(c=f[b],c===a)return this.values[b]},a.prototype.set=function(a,b){var c,d,e,f,g;for(g=this.keys,c=e=0,f=g.length;f>e;c=++e)if(d=g[c],d===a)return void(this.values[c]=b);return this.keys.push(a),this.values.push(b)},a}()),a=this.MutationObserver||this.WebkitMutationObserver||this.MozMutationObserver||(a=function(){function a(){"undefined"!=typeof console&&null!==console&&console.warn("MutationObserver is not supported by your browser."),"undefined"!=typeof console&&null!==console&&console.warn("WOW.js cannot detect dom mutations, please call .sync() after loading new content.")}return a.notSupported=!0,a.prototype.observe=function(){},a}()),d=this.getComputedStyle||function(a){return this.getPropertyValue=function(b){var c;return"float"===b&&(b="styleFloat"),e.test(b)&&b.replace(e,function(a,b){return b.toUpperCase()}),(null!=(c=a.currentStyle)?c[b]:void 0)||null},this},e=/(\-([a-z]){1})/g,this.WOW=function(){function e(a){null==a&&(a={}),this.scrollCallback=f(this.scrollCallback,this),this.scrollHandler=f(this.scrollHandler,this),this.resetAnimation=f(this.resetAnimation,this),this.start=f(this.start,this),this.scrolled=!0,this.config=this.util().extend(a,this.defaults),this.animationNameCache=new c,this.wowEvent=this.util().createEvent(this.config.boxClass)}return e.prototype.defaults={boxClass:"wow",animateClass:"animated",offset:0,mobile:!0,live:!0,callback:null},e.prototype.init=function(){var a;return this.element=window.document.documentElement,"interactive"===(a=document.readyState)||"complete"===a?this.start():this.util().addEvent(document,"DOMContentLoaded",this.start),this.finished=[]},e.prototype.start=function(){var b,c,d,e;if(this.stopped=!1,this.boxes=function(){var a,c,d,e;for(d=this.element.querySelectorAll("."+this.config.boxClass),e=[],a=0,c=d.length;c>a;a++)b=d[a],e.push(b);return e}.call(this),this.all=function(){var a,c,d,e;for(d=this.boxes,e=[],a=0,c=d.length;c>a;a++)b=d[a],e.push(b);return e}.call(this),this.boxes.length)if(this.disabled())this.resetStyle();else for(e=this.boxes,c=0,d=e.length;d>c;c++)b=e[c],this.applyStyle(b,!0);return this.disabled()||(this.util().addEvent(window,"scroll",this.scrollHandler),this.util().addEvent(window,"resize",this.scrollHandler),this.interval=setInterval(this.scrollCallback,50)),this.config.live?new a(function(a){return function(b){var c,d,e,f,g;for(g=[],c=0,d=b.length;d>c;c++)f=b[c],g.push(function(){var a,b,c,d;for(c=f.addedNodes||[],d=[],a=0,b=c.length;b>a;a++)e=c[a],d.push(this.doSync(e));return d}.call(a));return g}}(this)).observe(document.body,{childList:!0,subtree:!0}):void 0},e.prototype.stop=function(){return this.stopped=!0,this.util().removeEvent(window,"scroll",this.scrollHandler),this.util().removeEvent(window,"resize",this.scrollHandler),null!=this.interval?clearInterval(this.interval):void 0},e.prototype.sync=function(){return a.notSupported?this.doSync(this.element):void 0},e.prototype.doSync=function(a){var b,c,d,e,f;if(null==a&&(a=this.element),1===a.nodeType){for(a=a.parentNode||a,e=a.querySelectorAll("."+this.config.boxClass),f=[],c=0,d=e.length;d>c;c++)b=e[c],g.call(this.all,b)<0?(this.boxes.push(b),this.all.push(b),this.stopped||this.disabled()?this.resetStyle():this.applyStyle(b,!0),f.push(this.scrolled=!0)):f.push(void 0);return f}},e.prototype.show=function(a){return this.applyStyle(a),a.className=a.className+" "+this.config.animateClass,null!=this.config.callback&&this.config.callback(a),this.util().emitEvent(a,this.wowEvent),this.util().addEvent(a,"animationend",this.resetAnimation),this.util().addEvent(a,"oanimationend",this.resetAnimation),this.util().addEvent(a,"webkitAnimationEnd",this.resetAnimation),this.util().addEvent(a,"MSAnimationEnd",this.resetAnimation),a},e.prototype.applyStyle=function(a,b){var c,d,e;return d=a.getAttribute("data-wow-duration"),c=a.getAttribute("data-wow-delay"),e=a.getAttribute("data-wow-iteration"),this.animate(function(f){return function(){return f.customStyle(a,b,d,c,e)}}(this))},e.prototype.animate=function(){return"requestAnimationFrame"in window?function(a){return window.requestAnimationFrame(a)}:function(a){return a()}}(),e.prototype.resetStyle=function(){var a,b,c,d,e;for(d=this.boxes,e=[],b=0,c=d.length;c>b;b++)a=d[b],e.push(a.style.visibility="visible");return e},e.prototype.resetAnimation=function(a){var b;return a.type.toLowerCase().indexOf("animationend")>=0?(b=a.target||a.srcElement,b.className=b.className.replace(this.config.animateClass,"").trim()):void 0},e.prototype.customStyle=function(a,b,c,d,e){return b&&this.cacheAnimationName(a),a.style.visibility=b?"hidden":"visible",c&&this.vendorSet(a.style,{animationDuration:c}),d&&this.vendorSet(a.style,{animationDelay:d}),e&&this.vendorSet(a.style,{animationIterationCount:e}),this.vendorSet(a.style,{animationName:b?"none":this.cachedAnimationName(a)}),a},e.prototype.vendors=["moz","webkit"],e.prototype.vendorSet=function(a,b){var c,d,e,f;d=[];for(c in b)e=b[c],a[""+c]=e,d.push(function(){var b,d,g,h;for(g=this.vendors,h=[],b=0,d=g.length;d>b;b++)f=g[b],h.push(a[""+f+c.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+c.substr(1)]=e);return h}.call(this));return d},e.prototype.vendorCSS=function(a,b){var c,e,f,g,h,i;for(h=d(a),g=h.getPropertyCSSValue(b),f=this.vendors,c=0,e=f.length;e>c;c++)i=f[c],g=g||h.getPropertyCSSValue("-"+i+"-"+b);return g},e.prototype.animationName=function(a){var b;try{b=this.vendorCSS(a,"animation-name").cssText}catch(c){b=d(a).getPropertyValue("animation-name")}return"none"===b?"":b},e.prototype.cacheAnimationName=function(a){return this.animationNameCache.set(a,this.animationName(a))},e.prototype.cachedAnimationName=function(a){return this.animationNameCache.get(a)},e.prototype.scrollHandler=function(){return this.scrolled=!0},e.prototype.scrollCallback=function(){var a;return!this.scrolled||(this.scrolled=!1,this.boxes=function(){var b,c,d,e;for(d=this.boxes,e=[],b=0,c=d.length;c>b;b++)a=d[b],a&&(this.isVisible(a)?this.show(a):e.push(a));return e}.call(this),this.boxes.length||this.config.live)?void 0:this.stop()},e.prototype.offsetTop=function(a){for(var b;void 0===a.offsetTop;)a=a.parentNode;for(b=a.offsetTop;a=a.offsetParent;)b+=a.offsetTop;return b},e.prototype.isVisible=function(a){var b,c,d,e,f;return c=a.getAttribute("data-wow-offset")||this.config.offset,f=window.pageYOffset,e=f+Math.min(this.element.clientHeight,this.util().innerHeight())-c,d=this.offsetTop(a),b=d+a.clientHeight,e>=d&&b>=f},e.prototype.util=function(){return null!=this._util?this._util:this._util=new b},e.prototype.disabled=function(){return!this.config.mobile&&this.util().isMobile(navigator.userAgent)},e}()}).call(this);
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log($(this).val())` before the _switch_ statement to see what is there?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes the problem is that the function never gets called. so after i log it in the console before the switch statement, nothing appears = the function never gets called even when I change the option.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Tried it, and it did not work.

Comment: Should you really `echo` all your html? Can't you write it as normal html and use _php_ just to write content inside the DOM? I think it would solve your problem

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I don't echo all my HTML, I only echo the ones I showed because I thought it was needed as I'm using PHP to get the info from the options when I use the submit. I store them into $_SESSION variables immediately after the button is pressed.

Comment: _I think_.. the problem is because your `echo` occurs after `$(document).ready`

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes check the picture, I don't echo after $(document).ready

Comment: Show us: assets/js/custom.min.js source

Answer (score 0):

So first check solution with your dummy data:
https://jsfiddle.net/g3vczzqh/1/

I pasted some javascript that will solve your problem and I simplified your script a bit, you could of course further improve this. Also check comments inside code they are most helpful. There were quite a few issues with your code.

first you need to change select for post_tier you're missing id there:

```
<select name='post_tier' id="post_tier" style='width:100%;'>
```

then you didn't initialize newsrc variable, and your values were string so you had to parseInt before switch statement, and you had 0 in your switch statement and you have no 0 value in your select options (you do have 5 though). 
Also there is no need to write code twice, you could make some function out of it or simplify it a bit like in my example.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // initialize variables
   var newsrc, imgId;
   // you can add both ids in one change, but you're missing id in html select
   $("#tier, #post_tier").change(function(){
  // this is simple string check of id
  console.log($(this).attr('id'))
    if($(this).attr('id')==="tier"){
     imgId="#preTier";
  }else{
     imgId="#postTier";
  }
   // you need parseInt because your .val() numbers are actually strings
    switch(parseInt($(this).val())) {
            // you don't have value of 0 but you have value of 5
        case 5:
           newsrc = 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png';
            break;
        case 1:
            newsrc = 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png';
            break;
        case 2:
           newsrc = 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png';
            break;
        case 3:
            newsrc = 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png';
            break;
        case 4:
           newsrc = 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/peppers.png';
            break;
    }
     // just take that id and add newsrc
     $(imgId).attr("src",newsrc);

    });

    });
```

Comment: Hey @pegla thanks for all the help, do you mind checking out my new picture because it seems like nothing is happening even though your code snippet worked. Thanks.

Comment: What is line 6 in your custom.min.js? It seems like you're having issue there, could be that you didn't initialize variables same as in this example. Specifically WOW variable.

Comment: I am using a template and I changed the index file from .html to .php and had to modify it a bit, after my change the wow.min.js caused a problem with the scroll. I can't scroll down or up with the mousewheel nor with clicking on the middle mouse button. I tried adding it and noticed that it fixed the problem with the $(document) stuff. I have no idea how I am going to fix this scroll issue.

Comment: first try removing scripts one by one starting with that wow.min.js, then remove custom.min.js, then check if your script is working then try to add them one by one and resolve issues. I can't resolve everything for you without access to full source code. You should try reading documentation for those scripts you use (wow and custom), and dig deeper in javascript, find some tutorials online, you may find solution for yourself.